# A Scale Map For Texture Nodes?

Tags: node-editor, scale, procedural

I'm modeling a character and making a procedural skin shader, but I would like to fine control the scale of my bump maps (I'm using Voronois) since pores are different sized on different parts. I know I can't attach an image texture to the Scale of the Voronoi, but I was wondering if there is a way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can attach an image to the scale factor. It works pretty fine.

"..or into the scale factor of a mapping node, if the texture doesn't have its own 'scale' input" – Robin Betts
[image]

Comment: ..or into the scale factor of a mapping node, if the texture doesn't have its own 'scale' input

Comment: Huh! So it seems I didn't realize to use a math node, and I gave up too quickly. Thank you so much! It does indeed work perfectly.